# bootstrap: how to active a menu?

Tags: jsp, twitter-bootstrap

I have a menu in my header.jsp file. like this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">

<li  class="active"><a href="index.jsp">home</a></li>

<li><a href="product.jsp">product</a></li>

</ul>
```

Both index.jsp and product.jsp include header.jsp. By default, the Home item is selected and it is active. When I click product menu, it is navigated to product.jsp page, the product item should be active, my question is how to set the <li>Product</li> as class="active"?

Your answer is appreciated. Great thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to think about how you would identify what page is active and in turn tell the browser to apply the active class that that li .

One option would be to hardcode into each page's script;

```
//html
<ul class="nav nav-pills">

 <li id="home"><a href="index.jsp">home</a></li>

 <li id="product"><a href="product.jsp">product</a></li>

</ul>

 <script>
 $('#product').addClass('active');
</script>
```

but this is time consuming, especially if you have 6+ pages. There are far better and more dynamic ways of doing this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It would be better if it is not hardcode.

Comment: Perhaps then it might be better to include a bit of script to check what the current page is, check if the menu contains an ID that matches that, and apply the class. Could use the page title for this, or a hidden field on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but if you are looking for a jQuery-based front-end solution you could do something like:

```
$(function() {
    $('ul.nav li a[href$="' + window.location.pathname+ '"]').parent().addClass("active");
});
```

This will dynamically add an active class to the parent (in your case `<li>`) of the `<a>` element if the href attribute matches the URL path. The change you will need to make is to write the full path - so:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li id="home"><a href="/actual/site/path/index.jsp">home</a></li>
  <li id="product"><a href="/actual/site/path/product.jsp">product</a></li>
</ul>
```

This solution is not effected by hash or query parameters appended to the link as it only checks the path.